# Print all keys and value for HashBasedTable in Google Guava

Tags: java, guava

I create and populate a [Guava `Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) using the following code:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
table.put("A", "B", 1);
table.put("A", "C", 2);
table.put("B", "D", 3);
```

I wonder how to iterate over table and print out both keys and value for each row? So, the desired output is:

```
A B 1
A C 2
B D 3
```

Comment: Where is the API for this entity? Do you have a link to it (I don't use Guava, otherwise I'd know)? When you've reviewed it, does it tell you any methods that would likely be helpful to you?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table You might be looking for `#cellSet()`

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Im not Guava user so this may be overkill (if it is true then will be glad for any info) but you can use `table.rowMap()` to get `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` which will represents data in table in form `{A={B=1, C=2}, B={D=3}}`. Then just iterate over this map like:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map = table.rowMap();

for (String row : map.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Integer> tmp = map.get(row);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : tmp.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(row+" "+pair.getKey()+" "+pair.getValue());
    }
}
```

or

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String,Integer>> outer : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> inner : outer.getValue().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(outer.getKey()+" "+inner.getKey()+" "+inner.getValue());
    }
}
```

or even better using `com.google.common.collect.Table.Cell`

```
for (Cell<String, String, Integer> cell: table.cellSet()){
    System.out.println(cell.getRowKey()+" "+cell.getColumnKey()+" "+cell.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(table));
```

and the output will be

```
[{A={B=1, C=2}, B={D=3}}]
```